# Add a vector based on previous vectors

Tags: r, vector

Here is the data that I have:

```
round<-rep(1:5,4)
players<-rep(1:2, c(10,10))
decs<-sample(1:3,20,replace=TRUE)
game<-rep(rep(1:2,c(5,5)),2)
gamematrix<-cbind(players,game,round,decs)
gamematrix
```

Here is the output:

```
     players game round decs
 [1,]       1    1     1    2
 [2,]       1    1     2    2
 [3,]       1    1     3    1
 [4,]       1    1     4    2
 [5,]       1    1     5    1
 [6,]       1    2     1    1
 [7,]       1    2     2    1
 [8,]       1    2     3    2
 [9,]       1    2     4    1
[10,]       1    2     5    3
[11,]       2    1     1    2
[12,]       2    1     2    1
[13,]       2    1     3    3
[14,]       2    1     4    3
[15,]       2    1     5    3
[16,]       2    2     1    3
[17,]       2    2     2    2
[18,]       2    2     3    1
[19,]       2    2     4    1
[20,]       2    2     5    2
```

Now, I would like to add another column: "Same Choice" which I want to be "1" if the **same player in the same game** makes the same decision in next round as in previous round. For example, for player 1, the output should be: c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0).  Any ideas how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: `with(data.frame(gamematrix), ave(decs, players, game, FUN=function(x) c(0, !diff(x) )))`

Comment: Btw, good to use `set.seed` before generating random data, so we're all looking at the same thing. (See lmo's answer below.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` answer:

```
# set seed
set.seed(1234)

# load data
round<-rep(1:5,4)
players<-rep(1:2, c(10,10))
decs<-sample(1:3,20,replace=TRUE)
game<-rep(rep(1:2,c(5,5)),2)
gamematrix<-cbind(players,game,round,decs)

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(gamematrix)
dt[, .(decs=decs, lag=c(0,head(decs,-1)), 
                  sameDec=as.integer(decs==c(NA,head(decs,-1)))),
   by=c("players","game")]
```

I included the lag term so that you can verify.

@Frank s suggestion to use `shift` is much cleaner (and probably faster):

```
dt[, .(decs=decs, lag=shift(decs, 1), 
                  sameDec=as.integer(decs==shift(decs, 1))),
by=c("players","game")]
```

compared to my hand-coded lag.

Comment: I guess the idiomatic way would use `shift` instead of manually constructed lags, maybe like `dt[, same := decs != shift(decs), by=.(players, game)]` (Note that this gives NAs for the first round of each game... as I think it should.)

Comment: I fixed the NA issue. You are right that it is a bad idea to have a valid value there. I am working on including these `data.table` functions in my code... Thanks for the tip in `shift`.

Comment: Thanks, I used `data.table()` when testing.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work

```
library(dplyr)
gamematrix %>% as.data.frame %>% group_by(players, game) %>% mutate(new_col = ifelse(decs == lag(decs), 1, 0) )
gamematrix$new_col[is.na(gamematrix$new_col)]<- 0
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, I forgot about it